# Usage of "Android SIP Api" in general

Tags: android, api, sdk, sip, voip

I'm currently evaluating different approaches of voice-over-IP-calling on Android.
In the process of finding my favourite, I certainly came across the Android API itself.

Now if I search for "Android SIP Api" (or similar) here on SO, there is a disturbingly low number of results available. Also the majority is rather old.

I'm curious what the reason could be. Not a good solution, missing features, more valuable alternatives, misjudgement from my side ...